# Laravel slack notifications with access token instead of normal webhook

Tags: laravel, webhooks, slack-api

I want to send notifications using slack notification system.

I could not able to send notifications with the access token, provided by slack while user authenticates my bot.

Or is there way, I can get the incoming webhook from slack after authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to active by changing the webhook url to `https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage` and passing the `access_token` in slack headers.

Comment: Hey, Would you please, past you answer here ? So others can use or learn from that ?